# What is a shtuka?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

In the Berkeley lecture by Scholze, an $X$-shtuka over $S$ (usually $\operatorname{Spec}\bar{\mathbb{F}_p}$) is defined to be a rank $n$ vector bundle $E$ on $S\times_{\mathbb{F}_p}X$ together with a meromorphic isomorphism $\operatorname{Frob}_S^*E\to E$ (presumably meaning an isomorphism except for a codimension $1$ subscheme) which is defined on a subset that is fiberwise dense in $X$. It is stated that the $\ell$-adic cohomology of the moduli stack of shtukas can provide a global Langlands correspondence for function fields.

How does one understand this notion of shtuka? What does the pullback of Frobenius look like? Why is it defined this way?

Comment: Did you already look in this [introduction](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwido8eOt4T3AhWHzaQKHf6PAf8QFnoECAUQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.univ-paris13.fr%2F~ngodac%2FImpanga.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3dMHt96JbVdJ1VK6yufKzS)? Perhaps it is helpful.

Comment: Concerning the $\ell$-adic cohomology of the moduli stack of shtukas and the global Langlands correspondence for function fields see for example the article by [Lafforgue](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjB8PH3t4T3AhVUuKQKHQZxDXoQFnoECAkQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fvlafforg.perso.math.cnrs.fr%2Ffiles%2Fcht-ICM-lafforgue.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2CuCXIt0W_yQLx0koEbizh).